# Conditional sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, conditional-statements

I have this table in MSSQL:

```
ID   OP1   OP2  OP3
330   0     0    1
331   1     0    0
332   3     2    0
```

OP's are options. There can go from 1 to 9, 0 means that question was not answer.

How can i "sum" in a column called "Answered", like so:

```
ID   OP1   OP2  OP3  T
330   0     0    1   1
331   1     0    0   1
332   3     2    0   2
```

A value over 0, means answered.

I try with CASE WHEN, IF statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT Id, OP1, OP2, OP3, 
       (CASE WHEN OP1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN OP2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN Op3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 4):

Less cumbersome than case. [SIGN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx) gives 1 for a value > 0

```
SELECT
   ID,
   OP1,OP2,OP3,
   SIGN(OP1) + SIGN(OP2) + SIGN(OP3) AS T
FROM
   OPTABLE
```

Edit, May 2013. Actually, this can be simpler with

```
SIGN(OP1+OP2+OP3) AS T
```

Comment: Wouldn't SIGN(OP1+OP2+OP3) only give -1, 0, or 1? So it will never give 2 as required by the OP's example. Your original answer seems correct.

Comment: @Matt: it depends how you read "A value over 0, means answered". 0 or 1 may be enough

Answer (score 2):

Others have answered your question, but ideally you wouldn't store your data like that.

This table would be better:

```
id   op   value
330  1    0
330  2    0
330  3    1
331  1    1
331  2    0
331  3    0
332  1    3
332  2    2
332  3    0
```

Then you can get the sum for an ID with a simpler query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS T FROM table WHERE id = x AND VALUE > 0
```

It also scales better should you choose to add more options, and provides an easier way to data drive queries about particular option values.

Comment: Yep, but this table is not mine, i've to write a SP to add that column and fill it !

Answer (score 0):

how about the following:

```
SELECT ID,
       OP1,
       OP2,
       OP3,
       CASE WHEN OP1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
       CASE WHEN OP2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
       CASE WHEN OP3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS T
```

EDIT:

Comment: Won't work since he wants to count the occurences of values greater than 0, not sum the values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID,OP1,OP2,OP3,(OP1+OP2+OP3) AS T FROM OPTABLE
```

Comment: He doesn't want the sum, he wants the count of the ops that aren't 0.

Comment: mistake, didn't read the question properly. Your's is the one. Thanks.