# Create case and sum values based on condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a way to both rename values in a case statement, then group those values together as their sums. It seems that all explanations focus either on [creating the condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779196/conditional-sum-in-sql-server),[setting criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460328/use-comparison-signs-inside-a-sql-case-statement), or [summing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935265/select-query-with-case-condition-and-sum). I envision that the query should look something like 
this:

```
SELECT 
X, 
Y,
CASE Z
WHEN '1' THEN 'A'
WHEN '2' THEN 'B'
WHEN '3' THEN 'C'
WHEN '4' THEN 'D'
END +
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='1' OR Z='2' THEN 'I' END) +
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='3' OR Z='4' THEN 'J' END) AS Letters
FROM FOO
```

I may be making this more difficult than necessary. Really all I need is for `1` and `2` from `Z` to group into `I` and `3` and `4` from `Z` to group into `J` such that `I` will be the sum of all cases of `1` and `2` and `J` will be the sum of all case of `3` and `4`, ideally in the same column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As requested by the community, the input data would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO FOO 
(Z, Values)
VALUES
(1,3),
(2,6),
(3,10),
(4,20),
(5,1),
(1,9),
(2,12),
(3,30)
(4,40)
(5,2);
```

The outcome should create create a new category that sums values under `1` and `2` together under `I` and values under `3` and `4` together under `J`. Thus:

```
Letters Values
I       30
J       100
```

Where `5` is an excluded condition.

Comment: Please provide some example input and output data to illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As requested by @DaleBurrell, please provide input and output data as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. "Conditional SUM" examples can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql

Comment: Thanks Alex, I could use this solution if I could find a way to include two conditions under a single sum. Something along the lines of `SUM(CASE WHEN Z='1' OR Z='2' THEN I ELSE CASE WHEN Z='3' OR Z='4' THEN J END) Letters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE [Z]
            WHEN 1 THEN 'I'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'I'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'J'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'J'
       END [Letters]
       ,SUM([Values]) [Values]
FROM FOO
GROUP BY CASE [Z]
              WHEN 1 THEN 'I'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'I'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'J'
              WHEN 4 THEN 'J'
         END
```

Or slightly shorter

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN [Z] IN (1,2) THEN 'I'
            WHEN [Z] IN (3,4) THEN 'J'
       END [Letters]
       ,SUM([Values]) [Values]
FROM FOO
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN [Z] IN (1,2) THEN 'I'
             WHEN [Z] IN (3,4) THEN 'J'
         END
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dcfd7ebae7256273b7cbb13c81281dc)

Comment: You need to add a `WHERE [Z] IN (1,2,3,4)`.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I ran into some trouble because I was not complete enough in my question. I should have mentioned that I was using `ORDER BY` as well. Once I figured out the `CASE` statement needed to be included here as well, your solution worked without a hitch. Thanks Again.